# Matplotlib Sliders - Autoscaling of the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas, slider, autoscaling

For the simplicity, consider the following function : f(x) = A * sin(w * x). I use sliders to see the impact of a change in these two parameter, the code works very well, but i have a problem. If the amplitude A is too big, the maximum of the function are no more in the canvas (see [Picture of the resulting situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6VVA.png))... I tried some naive possibilities (see the code below) : defining the y-limits initially and update them at the same time than the function herself, but only the function changes in size, nothing happen to the y-axis...

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import numpy as np

## Slider parameters 

w_init = 1  # Initial value for slider 
w_min = 1   # Minimum value of slider
w_max = 10   # Maximum value of slider

A_init = 1  # Initial value for slider 
A_min = 1   # Minimum value of slider
A_max = 10   # Maximum value of slider


## Calculation
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
f =A_init * np.sin(w_init*x)

## Plot & Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.3)
tot_plot, = plt.plot(x,f, 'b')
plt.ylim(-A_init,A_init)


# Creates the axes for each slider
slidercolor = "blue"
w_slider_axe = plt.axes([0.15, 0.17, 0.7, 0.02])
A_slider_axe = plt.axes([0.15, 0.11, 0.7, 0.02])

# Creates the slider
w_slider = Slider(w_slider_axe, "w", w_min, w_max, valinit = w_init, valfmt="%.1E", color=slidercolor)
A_slider = Slider(A_slider_axe, "A", A_min, A_max, valinit = A_init, valfmt="%.1E", color=slidercolor)

# This function updates all the values of the function and draws the plot again
def update(val):
    f = A_slider.val * np.sin(w_slider.val * x)
    tot_plot.set_ydata(f)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    plt.ylim(-A_slider.val,A_slider.val)

w_slider.on_changed(update)
A_slider.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Someone knows how to fix it ? Sorry, I'm just a novice ;).
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've fix the "problem". It was really a detail but for a novice like me, it was not obvious.
Here it is the code that works very well :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import numpy as np

## Slider parameters 

w_init = 1  # Initial value for slider 
w_min = 1   # Minimum value of slider
w_max = 10   # Maximum value of slider

A_init = 1  # Initial value for slider 
A_min = 1   # Minimum value of slider
A_max = 10   # Maximum value of slider


## Calculation
x = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
f =A_init * np.sin(w_init*x)

## Plot & Slider

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.15, bottom=0.3)
tot_plot, = plt.plot(x,f, 'b')
ax.set_ylim(-A_init,A_init)


# Creates the axes for each slider
slidercolor = "blue"
w_slider_axe = plt.axes([0.15, 0.17, 0.7, 0.02])
A_slider_axe = plt.axes([0.15, 0.11, 0.7, 0.02])

# Creates the slider
w_slider = Slider(w_slider_axe, "w", w_min, w_max, valinit = w_init, valfmt="%.1E", color=slidercolor)
A_slider = Slider(A_slider_axe, "A", A_min, A_max, valinit = A_init, valfmt="%.1E", color=slidercolor)

# This function updates all the values of the function and draws the plot again
def update(val):
    f = A_slider.val * np.sin(w_slider.val * x)
    tot_plot.set_ydata(f)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
    ax.set_ylim(-A_slider.val,A_slider.val)

w_slider.on_changed(update)
A_slider.on_changed(update)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Add a hint as to what the essential change was - don't just drop the full working code!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example on dynamically changing axis ranges in pyplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import random

x = range(0, 10, 1)
y = range(-50, 50, 10)

xdata = []
ydata = []

plt.show()
plt.plot(x, y)

plt.axis([0, 200, 0, 200])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you but... what is dynamic in your example ? Can you use sliders to dynamically change your y-axis for example ?

Comment: I downvoted, since the answer does not answer the question of how to update the axis scaling when updating the plot interactively with a slider.